Testcontainers integration tests connection problems
I'm trying to create an integration testing environment using testcontainers. This is a integration between a database, a RabbitMq server, a Seq server and my application.
Following Microsoft's instructions, I used the WebApplicationFactory class to override the ConfigureWebHost method, with this theoretically being able to change the environment's default settings to one provided by the container created using the testcontainers providers.
During database configuration everything occurs as expected. However, the next service to be configured would be RabbitMq which is used as a Rebus transporter and this error is shown during configuration.
Rebus.Injection.ResolutionException : Could not resolve Rebus.Bus.IBus with decorator depth 1 - registrations: Rebus.Injection.Injectionist+Handler
---- Rebus.Exceptions.RebusApplicationException : Queue declaration for 'error' failed
-------- RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException : None of the specified endpoints were reachable
------------ System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
---------------- RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException : Connection failed
-------------------- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : This host is not recognized.

I came across a similar error configuring the application environment when I provided a wrong server address for RabbitMq, I suspect that the ConfigureWebHost configuration is being done before the RabbitMq container is available or the string that returns the GetConnectionString container method () is returning the incorrect value in relation to the format of the connection string with rabbitmq, which is usually something like this "amqp://user:password@localhost:port", while the return from GetConnectionString() could possibly be something like "http://localhost:port".
This ended up leaving me wondering whether the problem is with the container or the rebus configuration.
Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?
Below my webapplicationfactory:
public class IntegrationTestsWebApplicationFactory
    : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly PostgreSqlContainer _dbContainer = new PostgreSqlBuilder()
        .WithImage("postgres:latest")
        .WithDatabase("DB")
        .WithUsername("postgres")
        .WithPassword("postgres")
        .Build();

    private readonly RabbitMqContainer _mqContainer = new RabbitMqBuilder()
        .WithImage("rabbitmq:3-management")
        .WithUsername("guest")
        .WithPassword("guest")
        .Build();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            var dbContext = services
                .SingleOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<RedditCloneDbContext>));

            if (dbContext != null)
            {
                services.Remove(dbContext);
            }

            services.RemoveAll<IBus>();

            services.RemoveAll<Rebus.Transport.ITransport>();

            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
            {
                options
                    .UseNpgsql(_dbContainer.GetConnectionString())
                    .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
            });

            services.AddRebus(configure => configure
                .Logging(l => l.Serilog())
                .Transport(t =>
                   t.UseRabbitMqAsOneWayClient(_mqContainer.GetConnectionString())), true);
        });
    }

    public Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        _mqContainer.StartAsync();

        _dbContainer.StartAsync();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public new Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        _mqContainer.StopAsync();

        _dbContainer.StopAsync();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


I tried passing several different configuration parameters to RabbitMqBuilder, such as WithWaitStrategy without success, I also tried to ensure that it goes up on a specific port instead of a random port with WithPortBinding, I also tried hardcoding the rabbitmq url instead get from container builder and still the error remains.
